# WSO2 Identity Server dashboard widgets are empty

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to install the WSO2 Identity Server and run into the problem which I cannot resolve myself. Unfortunately Google search does not help at all. So the only hope is on the community here.

My setup: standalone WSO2IS behind apache2 reverse proxy. Software version 5.3.0; Java version "1.8.0_121"; OS: Debian 9.0 (kernel 4.9.0-1-amd64)

There are no problems with logging into the user dashboard, but trying to access the widgets gives empty pages. The behavior is exactly the same as reported by https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4141. It is marked as fixed, but looks like the problem still exists. Or I am doing something wrong.

Could anyone point me where to dig or how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the same config however on Debian 8 instead of 9.

My dashboard is now working well behind an apache reverse proxy. I followed the wso2 identity server configuration as described in [Isura's Blog](http://isurad.blogspot.de/2016/02/wso2-identity-server-510-behind_18.html) without the Nginx config.

In catalina-server.xml I set clientAuth="false" instead of "want", since this produced certificate error. It is behind the proxy, thus I don't see any big security issues.

The apache proxy with the mod_proxy_wstunnel installed has the following config:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://identity.local.domain:9443/$1 [P,L]

<Location />
       ProxyPass "https://identity.local.domain:9443/"
       ProxyPassReverse "https://identity.local.domain:9443/"
</Location>
```